# Example on Referential transparency (wikipedia)

Tags: functional-programming, coding-theory, imperative-programming

I have a rather foolish question on an example
explaining the idea behind [Referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency)

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency#Examples_and_counterexamples) is given an example i not understand:

> Consider a function that returns the input from some source.
> In pseudocode, a call to this function might be *GetInput(Source)*
> where Source might identify a particular disk file,
> the keyboard, etc. Even with identical values of Source,
> the successive return values will be different.
> Therefore, function *GetInput()* is neither deterministic nor
> referentially transparent.

I'm confused about the claim that
even with identical values of (variable) *Source*,
the successive return values will be different.

Eg if I tap an 'a' on my keyboard and apply *GetInput(Source)*,
it gives my 'a' as output. Then I tap again an 'a',
which of course is identical to my previuos input.
Next application of *GetInput(Source)* gives me again 'a'.

Therefore I not understand how is it possible that
*GetInput(Source1)* and *GetInput(Source2)* might give
different values if the two imputs *Source1* and *Source2*
are identical. Sorry, if it's too dumb, but I not understand
this quoted example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *Source* refers to the keyboard, and the user types <kbd>a</kbd> the first time but <kbd>b</kbd> the second time, then *GetInput(Source)* will not return the same value both times.

It's impossible to replace *GetInput(Source)* by its value without changing the meaning of the program, because there are many possible values, depending on the actions of the user. To replace *GetInput(Source)* with `a` would be wrong if the user decides to press <kbd>b</kbd>.

An example of a consequence of the fact that *GetInput(Source)* is not referentially transparent is that if the program calls this twice, which call returns `a` and which calls return `b` depends on the order in which the calls are evaluated (or more precisely, on the order in which the calls get their input from the keyboard: you have to get down to this level of detail to be sure).

Comment: oh yes, you are right, I confused that *Source* is the variable of the *input devise*, not the input itself, that's just the point, right?